# Remove Function for BST Does Not Remove Any Elements from the BST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I have a method that's supposed to remove the given element from a Binary Search Tree. However it doesn't actually remove any elements from the BST when I run the program.

I understand the idea of how this function is supposed to work: to set the root of the node with the given element to a different root, but I'm almost certain my approach to it isn't correct. I tried just setting the node of the given element to `null`, but that didn't remove anything either.

```
public boolean remove(int removalPoint) {

    int maxData = 0;

    if (root == null)

        return false;

    if (removalPoint == root.getData()) {

        if (getRightSubtree().root == null && getLeftSubtree().root == null)

            root = null;

        if (getRightSubtree().root != null && getLeftSubtree().root == null) {

            root = getRightSubtree().root;

            getRightSubtree().root = null;

            return false;
        }

        if (getLeftSubtree().root != null && getRightSubtree().root == null) {

            root = getLeftSubtree().root;

            getLeftSubtree().root = null;

            return false; 

        }

        if (getLeftSubtree().root != null && getRightSubtree().root != null) {

            maxData = getLeftSubtree().deleteMax();

            root.setData(maxData);

            return false;

        }

        if (removalPoint < root.getData())

            getLeftSubtree().remove(removalPoint);

        if (removalPoint > root.getData())

            getRightSubtree().remove(removalPoint);

    }

    return true;

}

public int deleteMax() {

    int maxData = 0;

    BSTNode RT = getRightSubtree().root;

    if (RT == null) {

        maxData = root.getData();

        root = getLeftSubtree().root;

    }

    else
        return getRightSubtree().deleteMax();

    return maxData;

}
```

The output from my test cases in the main function would look like this:

```
Remove 30, rc=false
        20
    19
        16
12
            9
        8
    6
            5
        4

Remove 20, rc=true
    19
        16
12
            9
        8
    6
            5
        4

Remove 4, rc=true
    19
        16
12
            9
        8
    6
        5

Remove 19, rc=true
    16
12
            9
        8
    6
        5
```

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, you check to see whether `root` has the data you are looking to delete from the tree.

What if `root` does not have the value you are looking to delete?

Also, as a general note, removal from trees is most elegantly done through recursion (although your method could work too). Here is one implementation of a node removal done recursively:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search-tree-set-2-delete/

Answer (score 0):

Eureka!. Turns out, it was my use of getRightSubtree() and vice versa that was causing the problem, I was supposed to just supposed to use my getRight and getLeft functions. From what I gathered, when I was using the Subtree methods for my if statements and such, the program was only checking the root of the Subtree and not the other nodes of the whole BST. I was also encouraged to change my deleteMax function up so that it returns a BSTNode as opposed to an Integer, cause it apparently made the last case easier to figure out. Here's my updated code:

`public boolean remove(int removalPoint) {

```
    if (this.searchRecursion(removalPoint) == null)

        return false;

    if (removalPoint < root.getData())

        root.getLeft().remove(removalPoint);

    if (removalPoint > root.getData())

        root.getRight().remove(removalPoint);

    if (root.data == removalPoint) {

        if (root.getRight().root == null && root.getLeft().root == null) {

            root = null;

            return true;
        }

        if (root.getRight().root == null && root.getLeft().root != null) {

            root = root.getRight().root;

            return true;

        }

        if (root.getLeft().root != null && root.getRight().root == null) {

            root = root.getLeft().root;

            return true;
        }

    }

    if (root.getLeft().root != null && root.getRight().root != null) {
        root.setData(root.getLeft().deleteMax().getData());

        return true;

    }

    return false;

}

public BSTNode deleteMax() {

    BSTNode maxData;

    if (root.getRight().root == null) {

        maxData = root;

        root = root.getLeft().root;

        return maxData;

    }

    return root.getRight().deleteMax();

}`
```